# C++ COM object as property

Tags: c++, com

I need a object of my library and especially as a property because I need it in my methods.

It works if I declare it as a local variable:

```
#import "...\library.tlb"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::IRobstepPtr interf(__uuidof(RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::Robstep));

    std::wcout << interf->Test() << std::endl;

    interf->ConnectToPlattform("192.168.0.1");
}
```

This works and does exactly what it should do. But how do get the "interf" variable as a property? I tried different things so far.

file.h

```
#import "...\library.tlb"

class robstep
{
public:
    robstep(void);
    ~robstep(void);

private:
    CComPtr interf; //Version 1
    CComObject<RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::Robstep>* interf; //Version 2
}
```

file.cpp

```
#import "...\library.tlb"

robstep::robstep(void)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    interf.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::Robstep)); //Version 1
    CComObject<RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::Robstep>::CreateInstance(&interf); //Version 2

}
```

I used this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181265) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396790/get-functions-objects-of-imported-tlb)

Do I have to cast it or something like this?

Comment: If you're talking about a member variable then do `RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::IRobstepPtr` just the same as you did in the working version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the first option `CComPtr<Interface>`.

If you're importing the TLB though, via `#import` you should have some smart pointer templates generated for you that you can use.

```
RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::IRobstepPtr interf;
interf.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Class));
```

Comment: I used CComPtr<RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::IRobstep> interf;
and interf.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::Robstep)); but that's pretty much the same right? Thanks btw

Comment: Yep, those are equivalent.

Comment: @Olli1511, please add that as an answer, even if you leave cocarin's answer as the accepted one, because that's exactly how you should declare the ATL field.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the accepted answer, here's mine solution for this problem:

```
CComPtr<RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::IRobstep> interf;
interf.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(RobstepRemoteLibraryCSharp::Robstep));
```